# VSCode Extension UI for multiple display langauges

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

My VSCode Extension contributes commands, settings, and a custom editor.
I figured out how to programmatically detect the VSCode display language and use it in the custom editor to provide multi-language UI.
However, I can't find a way to provide translation of the command title, the setting name, and its description to multiple languages and switch the language depending on the VS Code display language.

Is it possible?

Comment: have you looked at some of the default extensions of VSC, some use i18n

Comment: Hi, do you have more specific information about i18n?

Answer (score 0):

The official l10n (localization) sample extension shows a good example, as the old i18n (internationalization) sample has been deprecated.

Clone it here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/l10n-sample